# How we can only allow spinner to run when all validation passes in VF and JQuery?

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I am new to VF and JQuery. I have developed some validation code using VF and javascript and also have a spinner in place. When I click on Save button all validations are executing and spinner keep running which is bad. How we can only allow spinner to run when all validation passes?

**ActionSupportVFPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:includescript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includescript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" />
    <style>
    #spinner{
        display: none;
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
        font:normal 16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin-left: -100px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        z-index:2;
        overflow: auto;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        background-color:white;
        z-index:100;
        padding:5px;
        line-height:20px;
     }
     #opaque {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         z-index: 1;
         display: none;
         background-color: gray;
         filter: alpha(opacity=30);
         opacity: 0.3;
         -moz-opacity:0.3;
         -khtml-opacity:0.3
     }
     * html #opaque {
         position: absolute;
     }
  </style>
    <apex:form id="createform">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Case Create" />
        <apex:messages id="msgs" />
        <apex:pageBlock id="pblock" mode="mainDetail" title="Create Case">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" onclick="showSpinner()" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" onclick="showSpinner()" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsec" title="Details" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:inputField id="sub" value="{!case.Subject}" />
                <apex:inputField id="desc" value="{!case.Description}" style="width: 60%; heigth : 30%" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsection">
                <apex:inputField id="accId" value="{!Case.AccountId}" />
                <apex:inputField id="type" value="{!Case.Type}" />
                <apex:inputField id="prio" value="{!Case.Priority}" />
                <apex:inputField id="status" value="{!Case.Status}" />
                <apex:inputField id="origin" value="{!Case.Origin}" />
                <apex:inputField id="reason" value="{!Case.Reason}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <div id="opaque" />

        <div id="spinner" >
            <p align="center" style='{font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px;}'>
                <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/>&nbsp;Please wait
            </p>
        </div>
    </apex:form>

            <script>
            function showSpinner(){
                document.getElementById('opaque').style.display='block';
                var popUp = document.getElementById('spinner').style.display='block';
            }

            $ = jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var validator = $('[id="{!$Component.createform}"]').validate({
                    debug: true,
                    rules: {
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.accId}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.accId}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        },
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.origin}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.origin}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        }, 
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.reason}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.reason}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        },
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.type}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.type}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        },
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.desc}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.desc}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        },
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.sub}': {
                                required: function() {
                                    return $('[id="{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.sub}"]').val()=='';
                                }
                        },
                    },  // rules
                    messages: {
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.accId}':"AccountId must be provided",
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.type}':"Type must be provided",
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.origin}':"Origin must be provided",
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsection.reason}':"Reason must be provided",
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.desc}':"Description must be provided",
                        '{!$Component.createform.pblock.pbsec.sub}':"Subject must be provided",
                       }
                    }
                )});
        </script>
</apex:page>
```

Now if I dont pass any value and directly click on save, all validation executed, but spinner is keep rotating all the time. How we can correct it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner keeps rotating because you didn't declare an `invalidHandler`.
You're supposed to specify what the plug-in is supposed to do when some errors are detected. So here, you're supposed to hide the spinner like this:

```
var validator = $('[id="{!$Component.createform}"]').validate({
    debug: true,
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display='none';
    }
```